# How to integrate Rabbitmq authentication (using MQTT) with oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, rabbitmq, mqtt

I want to use oauth2 to authenticate and authorize the MQTT protocol in Rabbitmq.

I found out there [`rabbitmq-auth-backend-oauth2` plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-backend-oauth2) that helps deploy this purpose.

However, I cannot install this plugin on the Rabbitmq-server as its plugin.

- OS: Centos
- Rabbitmq 3.7.14
- Erlang 21

I installed this plugin with the command, but it's always failure:

```
make run-broker RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE = demo / symmetric_keys /
rabbitmq
```

Please let me know the deployment model of this integration and the configuration for rabbitmq, as well as installing the that plugin (of course if needed)

Comment: *How* is it failing? What happens? What is written into the log files?

Comment: Hi, I imagine the need to implement steps like this model is correct:
https://pasteboard.co/Ielk3uh.png
+ How to build and enable this plugin? I ran this command but failure:
#rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2
{:plugins_not_found, [:rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2]}

+ When I ran: #make run-broker RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=demo/symmetric_keys/rabbitmq
It's required elixir and then elixir required other services that I couldn't install because it's conflic with erlang21
+ How to config with new format in rabbitmq configuration file with structured Key = Value
Thank!

Comment: I edited model: https://pasteboard.co/IemRp7X.png